# Check and Uncheck Checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Why when I check the checkbox it works fine when I uncheck it nothing happen

[image: Checked] [image: Unchecked]

```
<form method="get">
    <table id="row">
        <tr><th colspan="2" >Location</th></tr>
        <tr><td>Country:</td><td><select id="country" name ="country"  style="width:200px"></select></td></tr>
        <tr><td>City:</td><td><select name ="city" id ="state"></select></td></tr>
        <script language="javascript">
            populateCountries("country", "state");
        </script>
        <tr><td></td><td><input onclick="myFunction()" type="checkbox" name="manualentry" value="manualentry" >Manual Entry</td></tr>
        <script>
            var table = document.getElementById("row");
            function  myFunction() {
                if (document.getElementsByTagName('manualentry').checked = true) {
                    document.getElementById("row").deleteRow(2);
                    var row = table.insertRow(2);
                    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                    var cell2 = row.insertCell(-1);
                    cell1.innerHTML = "City:";
                    cell2.innerHTML = '<input  type="text" >';
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("row").deleteRow(2);
                    var row = table.insertRow(2);
                    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                    cell1.innerHTML = "City:";
                    cell2.innerHTML = '<select name ="city" id ="state"></select>';
                }
            }
        </script>
        <tr ><td  colspan="2" align="right" > <input type="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things. `GetElementsByTagName` is the wrong function call, that method is used to get an array of elements by their actual HTML tag. Use `GetElementsByName` instead. Also, this call will return an array, so you need to specify which index it is (it will be index 0). Since `checked` is already a boolean value, you do not need to specify `== true`.

Replace `if (document.getElementsByTagName('manualentry').checked = true)`

with  `if (document.getElementsByName('manualentry')[0].checked)`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a `=` in the if condition:

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName('manualentry').checked = true) {
```

try

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName('manualentry').checked == true) {
```

Comment: With == nothing happen